# Angular 5 / Apache / No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cors

I'm working on with an apache2 / silex api with an angular 5 front.
I've no problem with my get requests, it's working fine, however, i can't troubleshoot my issue with POST, PUT or DELETE requests, i keep getting this error =>

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I searched thoroughly, and i think i do understand the cors concept, here's my .htaccess =>

```
DirectoryIndex bootstrap.php
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
  Allow from all
</Limit>

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L,E=HTTP_ORIGIN:%{HTTP:ORIGIN}]]
#Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
```

When i look up at my request tab in my chrome browser, i do see moreover that my options preflight request has "200 OK" status code and the response headers are those ones =>

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Max-Age:1000
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:574
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:Sun, 26 Nov 2017 10:18:21 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
```

I then do understand that the problem is that the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is missing in case of options preflight ( although this header is here with a get request,...

So my question is => is it possible, with .htaccess to answer to an option preflight automatically with the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header AND a 200 status and if so how ?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

PS: English being not my mother tongue, please excuse any errors,...

Answer (score 0):

As often, the simple fact to have to write down my question really helped to a better analysis of the situation,...

As said previously i found out that the problem was indeed with my htaccess, that didn't send the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header, and that was because i had write that in my htaccess =>

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

instead of =>

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

That was all ^^

I'll let this answer in case anyone would have the same problem than me,...

Have a nice day o/